# Get Listboxitem from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Hi this should be faily simple, however I don't know what I am doing wrong. I've been looking all over the internet seeing people make this work, even followed the tutorial on MSDN still nothing has worked for me.

I want to Iterate over a ListBox, and get the ListBoxItems so I can find the DataTemplate that I have added to it.

This is my code behind.

```
private void SetListBoxDataTemplate(ListBox MyListBox)
{
  try
  {
    foreach (CustomDataTemplateObject dataobject in MyListBox.Items)
    {
      ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)(MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataobject));
      ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(lbi);
      DataTemplate dt = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
      TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)dt.FindName("ListBoxItemTextBlock1", myContentPresenter);
      ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)dt.FindName("ListBoxItemComboBox1", myContentPresenter);

      tb.Text = dataobject.Text;
      cb.ItemsSource = dataobject.ListColors;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
  }
}
```

XAML looks like this:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemDataTemplate1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 1 0 1" MinWidth="50">
                <TextBlock Name="ListBoxItemTextBlock1" Background="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxItemComboBox1, Path=SelectedValue}" >
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <ComboBox Name="ListBoxItemComboBox1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>*

 <StackPanel>
    <ListBox Name="ListBoxTest1" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemDataTemplate1}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I have tried with setting my itemtemplate to static to see if it works, and the method i'm calling from code behind, is called after I have populated my ListBoxs

My dataobject is NOT null, however when i call the line in my code behind, my lbi, ends up being null.

Any suggestions? thanks in advance!

**FIRST UPDATE**

This problem only occurs if i call the method in my constructor, so perhaps it's because it hasn't initialized the full group element section yet. However I want to do this as soon as possible. Am I perhaps forced to do it in a WindowLoaded event?

**SECOND UPDATE**

Code updated, Rachel's answer worked for iterating over my ListBoxItems, however the Listbox Has not fully rendered since i'm unable to reach the Datatemplate at this time. So MyListBox_GeneratorStatusChanged is not working for this problem, but it does get the ListBoxItems.

Comment: `I don't know what I am doing wrong` - you're trying a winforms approach in WPF. Whatever you're trying to do here, you should do it using proper DataBinding as opposed to procedural code. You don't "iterate on a ListBox" in WPF because the Visual Tree is a complex structure and due to UI virtualization the ListBoxItems might not even exist at the moment your code runs.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i've been reading alot of places, I started doing the databinding which was fairly simple, I just felt like trying the other approach to broaden my horizon. However there is just alot of extra things to take into consideration when doing it the "Winforms" way.

thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF's main thread runs items at different [priority levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Code that runs in the Constructor all gets run at `Normal` priority, while things like rendering the `ListBox` and it's items run at the `Render` priority level, which occurs after all `Normal` priority operations have finished.

This means that your entire Constructor gets run (including `SetListBoxDataTemplate()`) before your `ListBox` is even rendered and the items get generated.

If you want to run some code after the items are generated, use the [ItemsContainerGenerator.StatusChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.statuschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event

```
// Constructor
MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += MyListBox_GeneratorStatusChanged;

...

void MyListBox_GeneratorStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // return if containers have not been generated yet
    if (MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status != GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        return;

    // remove event
    MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= MyListBox_GeneratorStatusChanged;

    // your items are now generated
    SetListBoxDataTemplate(MyListBox);
}
```

What are you trying to accomplish with this method anyways? It is a bit unusual for WPF, and there may be a much better WPF way of accomplishing your task.

**Updated based on new code added to Question**

A much better method of setting your `Text` and `ItemsSource` properties is to make use of WPF's data bindings.

Your `DataTemplate` should look like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemDataTemplate1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1 1 0 1" MinWidth="50">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Background="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxItemComboBox1, Path=SelectedValue}" >
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListColors}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>*
```

A `DataTemplate` is like a cookie cutter. It's used to make the UI objects, but is not part of the UI object itself. All it does is tell WPF that *"When you go to render this object, render it using this XAML"*. So the way your XAML gets rendered is

```
<ListBoxItem>
    <StackPanel>
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </Border>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListColors}">
    </StackPanel> 
</ListBoxItem>
```

In addition, the `DataContext` behind your `ListBoxItem` is the item from the collection bound to `ListBox.ItemsSource`, which based on your code should be `CustomDataTemplateObject`. That allows the bindings from the DataTemplate to work

If you're new to WPF and struggling to understand how exact the `DataContext` works, I'd recommend reading this article of mine: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/).

To summarize, WPF has two layers to an application: the UI layer and the Data Layer (`DataContext`). When you perform a basic binding like above, you are pulling data from the data layer into the UI layer.

So your `ListBoxItem` has a data layer of `CustomDataTemplateObject`, and the `TextBlock.Text` and `ComboBox.ItemsSource` bindings are pulling data from the data layer for use in the UI layer.

I'd also highly recommend using a utility like [Snoop](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1MSIM_enUS552US552&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wpf+snoop) which lets you view the entire Visual Tree of a running WPF application to see how items get rendered. Its very useful for debugging or learning more about how WPF works.

Comment: I was just trying to reach my inner datatemplate controls in different ways. Databinding is alot easier to work with in this case, rather than finding the template and then search it with datatemplate.findname and then do something with controls. 

In short, I was just trying to manually set my controls inside my innertemplate manually if it makes sense.

Comment: Oh another thing. Your code does not work. I'm going into my method, and i'm finding my listboxitems. so that part works. However, It has still not rendered my Contentpresenter of that element, so I can't find my Datatemplate and therefore not it's children either. I'll link some more code for you to see my intentions.

Comment: @MaxMazur A DataTemplate is like a cookie cutter. It's used to make the UI objects, but is not part of the UI object itself. All it does is tell WPF that *"When you go to render this object, render it using this XAML"*. So the way your XAML gets rendered is `<ListBoxItem><StackPanel><Border><TextBox></Border><ComboBox>`. There is no `ContentPresenter` or `DataTemplate` in that hierarchy. I'm going to write an update to my answer though explaining how to fix the rest of your code :)

Comment: Okay, do that.. However my code does work. I can find a Contentpresenter and I can find my attached datatemplate. The only problem is i'm not sure which event that is the first one to be able to run it right after the constructor has runned it's code.

But let me see what you got, i'm curious to see what you got :)

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing two jobs and mixing them into one. First, get access to the `ListBoxItem`:

```
private void SetListBoxDataTemplate(ListBox MyListBox)
{
    foreach (ListBoxItem listBoxItem in MyListBox.Items)
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can get the `DataTemplate` from the `ListBoxItem`:

```
foreach (ListBoxItem listBoxItem in MyListBox.Items)
{
    ContentPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(listBoxItem);
    DataTemplate dataTemplate = presenter.ContentTemplate;
    if (dataTemplate != null)
    {
        // Do something with dataTemplate here
    }
}
```

The `FindVisualChild` method can be found in the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

---

UPDATE >>>

To answer your edit, yes, the constructor will be too early to try to access these `DataTemplate`s because the Framework won't have applied them to all of the objects by then. It is best to use the [`FrameworkElement.Loaded` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do these kinds of things, as that is the first event that can be called *after* the controls have all been initialised.

Comment: Already did all that you just wrote.. My problem as Rachel writes is that my Listbox hadn't rendered in time, when I was trying to find my datatemplate of it. So when i wrote the findvisualchild method, I would receive a null value back. 

But thank you for your reply anyways ;)